# Multi segment curves in polygons (SDE)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, enterprise-geodatabase, curved

I'm looking for a tool, like [Curves and Lines](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=b59665cb906a435da3f8c45332d7cfdf)

that would work on polygon layer. At the moment I'm reshaping them feature by feature. Some notes about the data

1. We use Oracle Enterprise Geodatabase (That's all I know, we outsource servers and DB management)
2. Data originates from CAD (I was not there for the process, it was done before I came to work here, and it was outsourced)
3. Each parcel boundary is covered by line features, and each line break is defined by a point (I use the tool mentioned above for fixing the lines)

   4. I have ArcGIS 10.3.1

I've tried Smooth (arcTool) and other tools provided, but since the output is a separate shapefile, it's not useful for me, I need to maintain each parcel attributes and no deleting/adding parcels is preferred because other uses are constantly working on the areas I'm fixing (other operations).

[image]

The image shows how the parcel's curve is continuous vertices rather than being a true  curve.

It doesn't have to be a tool, If there's an more secure and reliable way to fix this problem.

Comment: I'm assuming that you are trying to round off the corner of a selected polygon.  Is that green line a true curve or a vertexed curve?

Comment: It's a vertexed curve, and at large number of polygons, causing to slowness on certain areas (while editing).

Comment: You can draw line, select it and split any polygon

Comment: Data is *never* "in ArcSDE". Please **edit** the question to specify the RDBMS in use and the geometry storage type within that database. You should also indicate how the CAD to GIS conversion was performed, and the version of ArcGIS in use.

Comment: I edited to the best of my knowledge.